# How can I get icon names sorted in GNOME Desktop on Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: gnome-shell, desktop-icons

I've installed Ubuntu 19.04 from scratch after an issue with my old Ubuntu installation.

I've found that now it uses GNOME instead of Unity. I like GNOME, but I have a couple of important usability issues that I assume are easily configurable, and I just don't know how to.

One of the main issues is that the full name of each file used to appear in Desktop icons, and if it were too long, when I clicked on the icon the full name would appear, even in long names.

Not now, as you can see:

[image]

I tried to search for these issues instead of asking, but I've not found anything that actually got them sorted.

Please note that I've installed GNOME Tweaks.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've found an answer to this! It'e extremely annoying and I don't understand why this question seems to be so uncommon (I didn't find anyone asking this, lt alone commenting on this!).

The problem is with the [Desktop Icons Extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1465/desktop-icons/). It does provide icons in the desktop, but in a weird way that its most annoying.

The solution? UNINSTALL IT FIRST and then install [Desktop Icons NG (DING) by rastersoft](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2087/desktop-icons-ng-ding/).

[image]

That did solved my issue.

Comment: Thanks for finding a solution and answering your own question. You can [*accept* your own answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) (It's absolutely fine) by clicking the tick (✓) next to it to indicate you've found a working solution and also so that others may more easily find it in the future.